# Como remover este slide automatico dos posts do blog?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, blogger

BLOG: http://1478562145.blogspot.com.br/

Eu estou querendo tirar este slide das postagens, mas se eu retirar alguma tag dos scripts, relacionada as imagens do slide, todas as fotos somem... Eu reduzi o blog o máximo que pude e todos os javascripts presentes ao serem retirados eles modificam o tal slide...

Só que o problema não é só este.. Se vocês clicarem para ler o post completo verão que eu colori uma parte do post, e ele está todo estruturado de uma forma diferente( e no caso a forma que eu quero que ele esteja ), mas o resumo automatico modifica a postagem e coloca o slide automático. Se eu excluir esta parte do código por exemplo:

```
expr:id=’"summary" + data:post.id’ style=’display:none;’
```

O post fica da forma que eu quero que ele fique e dá forma original, digamos assim... Mas ao fazer isso eu estaria perdendo o 'Ler Mais'.. E eu já tentei adiciona-lo de forma separada mas nunca funciona, porque ele já está no javascript, e se eu remove-lo tudo que contem dentro das postagens sumirá...

Existe algumas partes do javascript que ao remove-la o slide até para, mas as fotos ficam todas grandes e o texto fica formatado da forma que javascript mandar e não dá forma que eu editei... Como este aqui:

```
// Homepage Slider and Gallery Slider
$('.post-gallery').slick({
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
  adaptiveHeight:true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-nav slick-prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></button>',
    nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-nav slick-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>'
});
```

Eu tirei elemento por elemento dos javascript mas em vez de remover uma coisa só, ele apaga tudo... E uns nem acontecem nada. E eu estou de mãos atadas... Me ajudem por favor, me deem uma luz, uma dica, qualquer coisa... Eu estou tentando a dias, e nada que eu faço me ajuda a chegar em uma conclusão. Será que é possível remover o slide das postagens... ? se não, há como eu retirar este 'ler mais' e adiciona-lo em outro template sem ele?

> Como eu sei que eu talvez não tenha explicado direito... Vou resumir um pouco... Eu não quero que tenha o slide e nem que o texto fique formatado da forma que o javascript mandar, eu quero que o texto fique igual quando é clicado em 'Ler Mais', só que eu quero que isso aconteça antes do ler mais ser clicado.

Answer (score 1):

Para a função 'slick' existir no no seu script, foi necessário referenciar um script que é um plugin para slides. Então uma das coisas que você vai fazer é remover a referência desse plugin da sua página, para evitar deixar a página mais pesada atoa. Em seguida você vai remover todo esse código que você colou na descrição, abaixo de //Homepage Slider and Gallery Slider.

Geralmente esses plugins funcionam com uma lista de imagens marcadas como invisíveis no estilo e então o plugin vai alterando suas visibilidades em tempo de execução. Se for esse o caso, você vai pegar as imagens dentro da tag que a classe é 'post-gallery' e remover os estilos que as deixam invisíveis.

Comment: Exclui o <script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.5/slick.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>... E o código abaixo //Homepage Slider and Gallery Slider... Pesquisei sobre post-gallery no blog e marquei como comentário..  O slide parou, mas a postagem não está como ela fica ao clicar para ver o post completo... Clica no titulo da postagem, porque o 'Ler Mais' não está funcionando.

Comment: Não é pra comentar o que estiver com a classe post-gallery e sim descomentar as imagens dentro dele. 'post-galery' foi o nome de classe que escolheram para ser o envólucro do slider. O plugin recebia esse nome e criava as funcionalidades de slider pra qualquer tag que tivesse essa classe. Vou dar uma olhada, peraí.

Comment: Ahh olhei o código fonte da página aqui. Esses sliders estão sendo criados automaticamente pelo servidor né, então não sei se você deveria tentar tirar dessa forma. Aí tem que entender com mais calma como o servidor está montando as páginas.